# multiply binary numbers

Tags: digital-logic, logic-level

Is it any book which explains how to multiply binary numbers and how to create appropriate digital circuit schema?(i.e. digital schema which compute the multiplication of the binary numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any book on logic design should have that. I have used the following:

[http://www.amazon.com/Logic-Computer-Design-Fundamentals-4th/dp/013198926X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013198926X)

you can also find similar resources online:

Example:

http://people.ee.duke.edu/~krish/teaching/Lectures/arithmetic-circuits-2.pdf

This one uses half adders (HA) and full adders (FA) to construct the circuits.
Depending on how much detail you require this might be of help.